# Required property in a template type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

Considering a generic method, is there a possibility to set a constraint on the template type to have some specific properties?

In order to compile successfully the following code for example

```
public static int[] DoSomething<T> (T[] Input)
{
   int[] Output = new int[Input.Length];

   for (int i = 0;i < Input.Length;i++)
      Output[i] = (int)Input[i].PropertyA+(int)Input[i].PropertyB;

   return Output;
}
```

the template type needs to implement the PropertyA and PropertyB.
Is it possible somehow to set such a constraint on the template type?

**EDIT:**
And require in addition that PropertyA and PropertyB to be numeric types so they could be typed to int.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only possibility is to define T as type derived from some well known base class or implementing well known interface:

```
public interface IWellKnown
{
   int PropertyA { get; }
   int PropertyB { get; }
}
```

Any your method will be:

```
public static int[] DoSomething<T> (T[] Input) where T : IWellKnown
{
   int[] Output = new int[Input.Length];

   for (int i = 0;i < Input.Length;i++)
      Output[i] = Input[i].PropertyA+Input[i].PropertyB;

   return Output;
}
```

Edit:

Creating generic method working with any numeric type but just with numeric types is imho not possible because .NET doesn't have any base type like `Number`. So you cannot limit generic type to  numbers only. All numeric types are value types so you can do something like:

```
public interface IWellKnown<TData> where TData : struct
{
    TData PropertyA { get; }
    TData PropertyB { get; }
}
```

But in such case your interface  will accept any value type - any custom structure, char, bool, etc.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but what if I require those properties to be generally numeric, not necessarily integers. I put the question wrong, sorry. But thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to create such an restriction. You should check the input at runtime and throw a helpful exception error message.

You can however do something like:

```
public interface IWellKnown
{
   int PropertyA { get; }
   int PropertyB { get; }
}

public abstract class WellKnownBase<T> : IWellKnown
{
   IWellKnown.PropertyA { get { return Convert(this.PropertyA); } }
   IWellKnown.PropertyB { get { return Convert(this.PropertyB); } }

   public T PropertyA { get; }
   public T PropertyA { get; }

   protected virtual int Convert(T input) { return (int)input; }
}
```

Using such a base class guides the one implementing a concrete version to provide a way to cast to `int`. The explicit interface implementation provides access to `int` typed accessors while the "real" class still provides the original type.

```
public class WellKnownFloat : WellKnownBase<Float> {}
```

Would provide you with a class for float. If the type is not castable to int you can provide a custom converter:

```
public class WellKnownTimeSpan : WellKnownBase<TimeSpan>
{
    protected override int Convert(TimeSpan input) 
    { 
        return (int)input.TotalMilliseconds; 
    }
}
```

By the way, using linq and adding the requirement to the interface you can rewrite your function to `input.Select(x => x.PropertyA + x.PropertyB)).ToArray()`.

PS: please check the code using VisualStudio, I am just writing it out of my head without compiler support ;) There may be small compiletime errors.